# Why is this Rails regex matching this string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm using the following regex to validate one of my models

```
validates :login,
  :format => {:with => /[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]+/}
```

And one of my tests is failing because this regex is matching this string, passing it as valid

```
a+df
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It matches the `df` substring. Use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to force the regex to match the string in its entirety:

```
validates :login,
  :format => {:with => /\A[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]+\Z/}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex 
`^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]+$`

Comment: This could fail if the string contains newlines. In Ruby (unlike other regex flavors), `^` and `$` don't just match the start/end of the string, but also the start/end of individual lines in the string.

Comment: Yep, I just confirmed that this pattern would pass the following string "asdf\nasdf".  Thanks for the suggestion though, Oybek